# Color-Coding Microsoft Word Table Columns Depending on the String Data in the Cells, VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a way to save time in Microsoft Word. I am expected to adhere to a fast turnaround time every day, at work. I need VBA code to colour-code the background of certain table cells in Microsoft Word. I have 10 tables. In each table, I have hundreds of rows of data. Each row of data is a facility. Each facility is in one of 6 different geographical jurisdictions. Each geographical region has its own name (Northern, Southern, Eastern, Western, Central, Provincial). Each geographical region has its own color. I need to add that colour into the background of the columns of cells in the tables that reference the geographical region.

I currently copy and paste color formatting. It leads to mistakes. I am brand new with VBA. I tried to implement another solution someone had created for colour-coding based on numerical values but I was unsuccessful in my attempt to convert and adapt their code to regions.

I would feel super thankful if you could teach me. Thank you

Comment: Include more information about your attempts in the question, preferably the code you tried.

Comment: You can do it in Excel with conditional formatting then copy table to Word or you can embed Excel document in Word document.

Comment: Record a macro while you manually perform this task. That will at least give you a start on some code.

Answer (score 1):

For example, assuming your geographical region names (Northern, Southern, Eastern, Western, Central, Provincial) are in the 1st column of each table:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, Rw As Row
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  For Each Rw In Tbl.Rows
    With Rw.Cells(1)
      Select Case Trim(Split(.Range.Text, vbCr)(0))
        Case "Northern": .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        Case "Southern": .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdYellow
        Case "Eastern": .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        Case "Western": .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdPink
        Case "Central": .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdViolet
        Case "Provincial": .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdDarkYellow
      End Select
    End With
  Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```